# table of contents vba- Visible sheets only

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to create a VBA code that will only create a ToC for visible sheets. I found some VBA code online and modified it to include Visible = True in the loop, but the hidden sheets are still displaying when I run the macro. I've included the code below and would appreciate any advice on tweaking it to only display visible sheets.

```
Sub TableOfContents_Create()
```

'Add a Table of Contents worksheets to easily navigate to any tab

```
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim Content_sht As Worksheet
Dim myArray As Variant
Dim x As Long, y As Long
Dim shtName1 As String, shtName2 As String
Dim ContentName As String

'Inputs
  ContentName = "Contents"

'Optimize Code
  Application.DisplayAlerts = False
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Delete Contents Sheet if it already exists
  On Error Resume Next
    Worksheets("Contents").Activate
  On Error GoTo 0

  If ActiveSheet.Name = ContentName Then
    myAnswer = MsgBox("A worksheet named [" & ContentName & _
      "] has already been created, would you like to replace it?", vbYesNo)

    'Did user select No or Cancel?
      If myAnswer <> vbYes Then GoTo ExitSub

    'Delete old Contents Tab
      Worksheets(ContentName).Delete
  End If

'Create New Contents Sheet
  Worksheets.Add Before:=Worksheets(1)

'Set variable to Contents Sheet
  Set Content_sht = ActiveSheet

'Format Contents Sheet
  With Content_sht
    .Name = ContentName
    .Range("B1") = "Table of Contents"
    .Range("B1").Font.Bold = True
  End With

'Create Array list with sheet names (excluding Contents)
  ReDim myArray(1 To Worksheets.Count - 1)

  For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If sht.Name <> ContentName Then
      myArray(x + 1) = sht.Name
      x = x + 1
    End If
  Next sht

'Alphabetize Sheet Names in Array List
  For x = LBound(myArray) To UBound(myArray)
    For y = x To UBound(myArray)
      If UCase(myArray(y)) < UCase(myArray(x)) Then
        shtName1 = myArray(x)
        shtName2 = myArray(y)
        myArray(x) = shtName2
        myArray(y) = shtName1
      End If
     Next y
  Next x

'Create Table of Contents
  For x = LBound(myArray) To UBound(myArray)
    Set sht = Worksheets(myArray(x))
    sht.Activate
    With Content_sht
      .Hyperlinks.Add .Cells(x + 2, 3), "", _
      SubAddress:="'" & sht.Name & "'!A1", _
      TextToDisplay:=sht.Name
      .Cells(x + 2, 2).Value = x
    End With
  Next x

Content_sht.Activate
Content_sht.Columns(3).EntireColumn.AutoFit


ExitSub:
'Optimize Code
  Application.DisplayAlerts = True
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

The `.Visible` property of the worksheet has three options:

[image]

As you can probably imagine, 0 is converted to `False`, and 1 or 2 to `True`. This causes errors, if you try to convert `.Visible` to a `Boolean` value.

Thus the idea is to loop only through worksheets, that are `xlSheetVisible`. Checking simply `sht.Visible` can lead to an error, if the sheet is `xlSheetVeryHidden`, because `xlSheetVeryHidden` is evaluated to `True`:

```
Public Sub TestMe()
    Dim sht As Worksheet    
    Set sht = Worksheets(1)
    sht.Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
    Debug.Print CBool(sht.Visible)  'prints true
End Sub
```

Thus use:

`If sht.Visible = xlSheetVisible and sht.Name <> ContentName`

Comment: I tried adding  sht.Visible = xlSheetVisible and the ToC now only shows the title ("Table of Contents"). Also got an error- subscript out of range, which I'm curious about.

Comment: @smurfimpulse - try to find a way to assign `myArray` only to the visible sheets. This `ReDim myArray(1 To Worksheets.Count - 1)` takes also the hidden and the very hidden ones.

Answer (score 0):

loop only through visible sheets:

If sht.Name <> ContentName And sht.Visible Then

Comment: It is a bit dangerous to assume that `sht.Visible` is converted to boolean the way you want it.